# How to stop Rest APi call /search/query to not include contents of the folders in the result

Tags: search-results, search-query

I was jsut wondering if its possible to refine searchquery to not to include contents of the folders. I have a query like this

```
POST request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [                 
                "driveItem", "listItem", "list"                
            ],
            "query": {

"queryString": "filename: cd* Path:https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/Testing/ AND ParentLink:/Folder1/InsideFolder1",
```

If there are folders inside InsideFolder1 the result will list the files/contents that are in those folders.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior so the only files/folders that are at the ParentLink level are returned.

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you asking to only return folders and not files?

Comment: No I do what to return folders and files but only at the level of parentLink /Folder1/InsideFolder1 The call mentioned in my question returns more than I want.If there is a folder like /Folder1/InsideFolder1/folderA and there is a fileA in it. I only want to get folderA and not fileA which is currently returned

Comment: OK, I suspect you'll have to "take what you can get" from the API and then perform additional filtering in your app. Have you tried changing your query to remove the `contains operator :` and replace it with an equals operator `ParentLink=/Folder1/InsideFolder1`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried but with the same result.